# Python, Keypass how can I read the Tag information from group

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I read the TAG information from a group object? I can read it with an entry but not with a group.

I am trying to extract the Tag information from a group entry in keypass file, the tag information includes information that allows to calculate some information needed build password of entry!